# How to put paragraphs inside PHP contact form?

Tags: php, html, email, contact-form

I programmed a contact form in PHP and I want to include paragraphs in the message that gets send, so that the user would have to write in certain paragraphs and not just one block of text.

I've tried to split the `message` into multiple `textareas`, but I don't know how I should adjust the PHP code so that these `textareas` would get send inside one `message` in the right order. Each `textarea`should've presented one paragraph.

This is my PHP:

```
<?php 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: mywebsite.com'; 
    $to = 'myemailadress@adress.com'; 
    $subject = 'subject line';
    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '. $email. "\r\n" .
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email. "\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    $status = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if ($status) { 
        echo '<p style="color: white">Your Message was sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p style="color: white">Something went wrong. Please try again.</p>'; 
    }
?>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact-form-handler.php">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
        <br>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
        <br>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="30" required></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="SEND MESSAGE">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Danyal Sandeelo, not really helping him with his question.

Comment: @Jah thanks. Can you help me? I'm not really good at PHP.

Comment: sorry i only see one textarea, how are you creating multiple?

Answer (score 0):

I have add:

```
$message = nl2br($message); // Inserts HTML line breaks <br />
```

this should Insert HTML line breaks.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: mywebsite.com';
$to = 'myemailadress@adress.com';
$subject = 'subject line';
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$message = nl2br($message); // <-- added to Inserts HTML line breaks.

$status = mail($to, $subject, nl2br($message), $headers);

if ($status) {
    echo '<p style="color: white">Your Message was sent!</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p style="color: white">Something went wrong. Please try again.</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

When you use nl2br you can change the "\n" from the textarea to a "
".
You can send a content-type: text/plain mail to and don't have to transform the newline characters into 
 tags.

I don't see multiple textareas in your code so i guess nl2br is the function you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I think it would be easier if I create one textarea for each paragraph.Don't get me wrong, I'm grateful for your idea.But my impression is that it would be easier for the user to have multiple textareas rather than one big one with paragraphs in it.I'm sorry for not expressing this clear enough, but I will definitely check this function out!If I have 3 textareas,how can I modify the ```$message = $_POST['message'];``` so that it gets every textarea?Should I use 3 classes ```message ; message_1 , message_2``` and just write ```$message = $_POST['message'; 'message_1' ; 'message_2'];```?

Comment: if you have mutiple textareas just give them different names or even use name="message[]" to get an array of messages. Than you can join them with the php-function implode($_POST['message'], '<br>') to sepeate them into paragraphs inside the email.